# how to make football image in open gl without using built in command for transformation(gltranslatef ,glrotatef , glscalef)

Tags: opengl

[[image]]

can any one help me in making is object via transformation( Translation ,Rotation , Scaling ) in 2D without using built in command for transformation(gltranslatef ,glrotatef , glscalef)

Comment: Making an object via transformaton? Transformations can't compose objects from nothing. You'll need something which can be transformed first. So can you please elaborate on what exactly you need?

Comment: thanks .....but it was done

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<GL\glut.h>
```

## include

void molana_football();

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);

glutInitWindowSize(720, 480);

glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);

glutCreateWindow("Football");

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

glutDisplayFunc(molana_football);

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 0, 480);

glutMainLoop();
return 0;
```

}
void molana_football()

{

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

float x1, y1, x2, y2;

float angle;

double radius = 100 * 1.5;

x1 = 300 * 1.5, y1 = 200 * 1.5;

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

glColor3f((GLfloat)1.0, (GLfloat)1.0, (GLfloat)1.0);

for (angle = 1.0f; angle<361.0f; angle += 0.2)

{

    x2 = x1 + sin(angle)*radius;

    y2 = y1 + cos(angle)*radius;

    glVertex2i(x2, y2);

}
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glColor3f((GLfloat)1.0, (GLfloat)0.0, (GLfloat)0.0);

glVertex2i(300 * 1.5, 200 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(270 * 1.5, 190 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(265 * 1.5, 160 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(300 * 1.5, 150 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(320 * 1.5, 175 * 1.5);

glEnd();

int tx = 0; int ty = 10;

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);


glVertex2i(300 * 1.5 + tx, 190 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(320 * 1.5 + tx, 230 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);


glColor3f((GLfloat)0.9, (GLfloat)1.0, (GLfloat)0.0);

glVertex2i(320 * 1.5, 240 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(295 * 1.5, 260 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(310 * 1.5, 290 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(345 * 1.5, 285 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(350 * 1.5, 257 * 1.5);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(295 * 1.5 + tx, 250 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(270 * 1.5 + tx, 245 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(270 * 1.5 + tx, 180 * 1.5 + ty);
glVertex2i(250 * 1.5 + tx, 210 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glColor3f((GLfloat)0.0, (GLfloat)0.0, (GLfloat)1.0);


glVertex2i(250 * 1.5, 220 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(270 * 1.5, 255 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(240 * 1.5, 270 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(215 * 1.5, 250 * 1.5);


glVertex2i(215 * 1.5, 225 * 1.5);

glEnd();


glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(215 * 1.5 + tx, 215 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(210 * 1.5 + tx, 160 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(265 * 1.5 + tx, 150 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(235 * 1.5 + tx, 145 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glVertex2i(235 * 1.5, 155 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(210 * 1.5, 170 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(206 * 1.5, 160 * 1.5);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glVertex2i(235 * 1.5, 155 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(245 * 1.5, 125 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(230 * 1.5, 130 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(206 * 1.5, 160 * 1.5);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(320 * 1.5 + tx, 165 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(350 * 1.5 + tx, 170 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(350 * 1.5 + tx, 247 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(370 * 1.5 + tx, 200 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glVertex2i(350 * 1.5, 180 * 1.5);


glVertex2i(370 * 1.5, 210 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(395 * 1.5, 190 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(390 * 1.5, 165 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(370 * 1.5, 155 * 1.5);

glEnd();


glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(370 * 1.5 + tx, 150 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(330 * 1.5 + tx, 95 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(300 * 1.5 + tx, 140 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(305 * 1.5 + tx, 110 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(245 * 1.5 + tx, 115 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(290 * 1.5 + tx, 90 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glVertex2i(305 * 1.5, 120 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(330 * 1.5, 105 * 1.5);

glVertex2i(290 * 1.5, 100 * 1.5);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

glVertex2i(310 * 1.5 + tx, 280 * 1.5 + ty);

glVertex2i(300 * 1.5 + tx, 290 * 1.5 + ty);

glEnd();

//scaling

  int sx = 1; int sy = 2;

  glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);


  glVertex2i(240 * sx*1.5, 135 * sy*1.5);

  glVertex2i(260 * sx*1.5, 145 * sy*1.5);

  glEnd();

glEnd();

glFlush();
```

}